# How do I pass values of spinner to another activity and display them in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, spinner

I've created 2 projects. One is to key in personal information and second application is where there's ListView displayed of the information that's keyed in. I've a spinner in the 1st application. I'm not sure how to pass the values of spinner to a listview in another activity.

Below is the 2nd application.

```
package main.page;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.AutoCompleteTextView;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class SavedInfo extends ListActivity
{
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.saved_info);

        Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();

        String name = b.getString("name");
        String date = b.getString("date");
        String type = b.getString("type");
        String likes = b.getString("likes");
        String dislikes = b.getString("dislikes");

        Spinner fullName = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.fName);
        TextView da = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.date);
        TextView ty = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.type);
        TextView like = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.likes);
        TextView dislike = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.dislikes);

        fullName.setOnItemSelectedListener("Full Name: " + name);
        da.setText("Date: " + date);
        ty.setText("Type: " + type);
        like.setText("Likes: " + likes);
        dislike.setText("Dislikes: " + dislikes);

    }   
}
```

I'm not sure if I've set the spinner right or wrong. I'm not sure how to set it too. Anyone knows how?
Thanks

Comment: docked a point. won't answer if if don't accept.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

get the text from the spinner and send it with an intent

```
String text = fullname.getSelectedItem().toString();
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("spinnerText", text);
intent.setClass(this, /*TODO Class to open*/);
startActivity(intent);
```

then in the onCreate of the other activity

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String text = intent.getStringExtra("spinnerText");
//TODO do what you want with your text
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok.  Well I am assuming that you mean pass values of spinner to another activity.  If you mean literally another application that is more complicated and might involve something like a shared remote service.  But for an passing to another activity you would just send ant intent to that activity using

```
 startActivity(intent);
```